# Making formulas

Tags: linear-algebra

Sam is paid to work at a chemist shop after school

He receives an extra $\$2$ for each delivery he makes.

One day he makes $5$ deliveries and is paid a total of $\$25$.

If $d$ is the number of deliveries:

Give the formula for the wages, $P$, that he receives each day.

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

If he was paid $\$2$ for each delivery, and he made $5$ deliveries, how many of the twenty-five dollars came from making deliveries? Keeping that in mind, how much must've come from just showing up for work (and doing stuff other than deliveries)? Now put it together into a formula, filling in the two blanks
$$
P = \_\cdot k + \_
$$